# bookshelf/knex add time to timestamp

Tags: node.js, datetime, timestamp, knex.js, bookshelf.js

Using NodeJS, Knex, Bookshelf JS ORM, and PostgreSQL, I have a field `table.timestamp('reset_password_expires');` - how can I set the date for future (let's say 10 minutes from now)?

I've tried:

```
new User.User({'email': email}).fetch().then((user) => {
      user.set('reset_password_expires', Date.now() + 60000);
      user.save();
      ...
```

But this throws:

> Unhandled rejection error: date/time field value out of range:
>   "1544577763253"

Also tried

```
user.set('reset_password_expires', 'NOW()' + '10 minutes'::interval);
```

But this is invalid syntax.

I've also tried changing field type to `dateTime`, with the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think PostgreSQL requires timestamp to be on ordinary datetime format (as described [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/datatype-datetime.html)). At the moment you are passing milliseconds since epoch.

In Developer Tools:

```
> Date.now() + 60000
1544706877041
```

You can try using this instead:

```
new Date((new Date()).getTime() + 60000)
```

In Developer Tools:

```
> new Date((new Date()).getTime() + 60000)
Thu Dec 13 2018 14:15:50 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

Here is a utility function that I use myself:

```
module.exports.inHours = (hours) => {
  const minutes = hours * 60;
  const seconds = minutes * 60;
  const milliseconds = seconds * 1000;

  return new Date((new Date()).getTime() + milliseconds);
};
```

My code looks slightly different than yours, but this is how I call the function:

```
await userQueries.update(user.user_id, {
  resetPasswordToken: resetToken,
  resetPasswordExpires: inHours(1),
  modified_at: new Date(),
});
```

This is a datetime, however, not a timestamp.